# How to reduce a javascript array into half?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, crossfilter

I have an array containing 365 objects (date and value), and I would like to reduce this into half to make plotting faster. The reduction has to occur such that I get every other point in the array. So if the first element is for Jan 1, the second element would be for Jan 3 instead of Jan 2. I can iterate through the array and if the number is odd I can add that to the new array or vice versa. But is there a better/faster way to achieve this? I heard crossfilter.js is made for things like this, but wasn't able to figure out how to use it for this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it'll be better if you add your sample data too, to the question

Comment: Specifically, is the array already sorted by date and is it contiguous (i.e. no gaps)?

Answer (score 3):

reduce or filter will work for this.

```
array.reduce(function(memo, item, index) { 
  index % 2 && memo.push(item); 
  return memo; 
}, [])

array.filter(function(item, index) { return index % 2; })
```

Comment: **if the first element is for Jan 1, the second element would be for Jan 3 instead of Jan 2** this means OP wants to filter based on value , not index

Comment: Regardless, imo, `.filter()` is a better fit for this problem.

Comment: yes filter is better i agree, but your answer is wrong, when there is array with just `[1,3,5,6]` , what would your code output: `[3,6]` right? so this is **wrong answer**

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz you're right. I should delete my answer and vote to close the question. the question is incredibly poorly asked and its impossible to know how to answer

Comment: @JakeBurkhead no dont delete the answer, it could be right, not yet clear what op wants

Comment: @Jack, well reduce can do everything that filter can do.

Comment: @Pacerier it does indeed, but reduce is also the heavier tool on the belt :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `Array.filter`. `filter` can be used to filter out the required values from an array, it will result in an array with length lesser or equal to the original array.

The below code returns all the odd elements in the array:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

array.filter(
    function (d,indx) { 
        return indx%2 != 1
    }
)
```

Comment: **if the first element is for Jan 1, the second element would be for Jan 3 instead of Jan 2** this means OP wants to filter based on value , not index

Comment: A similar method would easily work if the array is sorted by date

Comment: yes it can, but tell me, when there is array with just `[1,3,5,6]` , what would your code output: `[3,6]` right? so this is **wrong answer**

Comment: Ok, now it returns `[1,5]`

Comment: so it still gets 1, and 5, they are still odd, should have only returned `6` as it is the only even value

Comment: Wait, I'm failing to see your point.  The question said **The reduction has to occur such that I get every other point in the array**, that's it, right? Irrespective of the value, i think going by the odd indices satisfies the OPs requirement.

Comment: **if the first element is for Jan 1, the second element would be for Jan 3 instead of Jan 2** every odd point means, every odd value, not index

Comment: Ohh ok, I took the assumption that he quoted that from his actual data, where he has 365 points, one for each day. I think its best to wait for the OP to make an edit, to clarify his intention

Comment: removed the downvote, better close as unclear what asking, untill op edits

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function of array

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var odds = numbers.filter(function(index, item) {
    return index % 2 == 1;
});
```

Comment: map returns something for every element in the array. so that will return an array the same length as the input.

Comment: yes, actually it is filter function, corrected the answer